# Saving transformed image on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have a JavaServletPage where you can upload and crop (with JCrop) an image. The other Servlet handles the request and applys the crop transformation, but how can I save the new transformed image?

I have found a solution (I didn't try it yet) that needs another Servlet, which accepts the cropped image and stores it in the blobstore (via POST method again). But this seems really complicated for such a simple task.

Is there another way to save my transformed image?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the file into the Blobstore or into Google Cloud Storage after applying the transformation. Here is an example: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore